# Hiding variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What's the best practice for hiding variables in a Ruby file, like the equivalent of a (function() {})() closure in JavaScript?

So if I have a file:

```
foo = 5
bar = foo * foo
```

I only want to expose bar, not foo, when someone requires it.

Comment: Ruby is object-oriented. Use classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a file containing those two lines and someone requires that file, neither of the two variables will be exposed. Local variables are still local to the file even if they appear at the global scope.

If you want to expose `bar`, you'll need to turn it into a global variable `$bar` or, if you don't intend for the variable to change, into a constant `Bar`. By not doing the same thing to `foo` it will automatically not be exposed.

You might also consider wrapping the whole thing up in a module or class.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has scope as many other languages do.  Variables are declared the first time they are used and will have scope based on where they are declared.  If you use a local to a function:

```
def do_something
  foo = 5
  foo * foo
end

puts do_something
```

It will print 25, but foo will not be available outside of the `do_something` function.

Is this what you're looking for?

This post talks about Ruby's scoping in more depth [Ruby Scoping Rules](http://penberg.blogspot.com/2009/06/ruby-scoping-rules.html).

Comment: Actually I'm going to use a variant of this, foo = lambda { ... }.call though I appreciate the comment about using classes for a more robust solution.